# Limit of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous and differentiable function on interval $(0, \infty)$ and let $ \lim f'(x) = 0$ when x tends to infinity. Prove that $\lim g(x)=0$ when x tends to infinity, where $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$. It's intuitive to me that this is true, but I have no idea how to prove it rigorously, I used some methods, but I doubt that it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\xi)$ where $\xi \in [x,x+1]$.

Comment: Marvelous idea! Thank you! I think I solved it, so basically by Lagrange's theorem there exists c(x) in in interval [x,x+1] such that it holds what you wrote, and if I take f'(c(x)) where x tends to infinity I will get the desired result, correct?

Comment: @DarkoDekan  Yes,